# How do I generate a report that has all the issues?

Tags: fortify

I have a Fortify FPR scan file that I open in AWB. I want to generate a report that has all the instances of where the issues are found. When I generate a report it generates the report with the issues by type and their count and below the type I also get names and code snippets of *some* files where the issue was found. I want to generate s report which has names and code snippets from *all* files in which issues were found. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Audit Workbench, generate your report and under the 'Results Outline' panel Open up the Listings section and then uncheck the Limit number of issues in each group setting if checked.

[image: Fortify report settings]

Answer (score 10):

The template files can be found in `Core/config/reports` of your fortify directory.

Copy DeveloperWorkbook.xml to a new file `AllIssues.xml` and near `<title>Results Outline</title>` edit `limit="5"` to `limit="-1"`.

Then run:

```
ReportGenerator -template AllIssues.xml -format pdf -f output.pdf -source input.fpr
```

Answer (score 0):

had you look at the following command:

$ **ReportGenerator -format PDF -f abcd.pdf -source abcd.fpr**

Thanks,

Marcelo Muzilli