# Forttify dynamic-code-evaluation-unsafe-deserialization on Spring Boot Actuator 2.1.6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, fortify

I  have the same problem as in the  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945590/dynamic-code-evaluation-unsafe-deserialization-spring-boot-2-how-to-avoid-a), the only answer is to upgrade the spring-boot version to 2.0.6. However, I currently have version 2.1.6.RELEASE and I still have the same vulnerability in the report.

Answer (score 1):

Your scan report should have an abstract, explanation, and recommendation for the issue. (Here are a few links to help you generate the report - [Fortify file (.fpr file) to PDF convertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921252/fortify-file-fpr-file-to-pdf-convertion/37922431), [How do I generate a report that has all the issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288065/how-do-i-generate-a-report-that-has-all-the-issues))

In short, this issue is because SpringBoot Actuator exposes JMX management endpoints by default. JMX uses Java serialization to send/receive messages, an attacker that is able to connect and authenticate to the Actuator JMX endpoints will be able to send a malicious Java serialization payload which may run arbitrary code upon deserialization by the JMX endpoint.

---

**Fix**:
SpringBoot Actuator JMX endpoints may be disabled by adding the following properties
to the application.properties file:

```
endpoints.jmx.enabled=false
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=*
```

Note: endpoints.jmx.enabled=false is deprecated

There's also a nice answer on [MicroFocus](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Fortify-User-Discussions/Dynamic-Code-Evaluation-Unsafe-Deserialization/td-p/1683229)